# Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I can't seem to send email using java and was hoping you guys could help.  Here's the code I'm using now (I've actually tried several examples and none of them work).

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Mail {

    static Properties mailServerProperties;
    static Session getMailSession;
    static MimeMessage generateMailMessage;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        generateAndSendEmail();
        System.out.println("\n\n ===> Your Java Program has just sent an Email successfully. Check your email..");
    }

    public static void generateAndSendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

//Step1     
        System.out.println("\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
        mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // TLS Port
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // Enable Authentication
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // Enable StartTLS
        System.out.println("Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..");

//Step2     
        System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
        getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
        generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("test@google.com"));
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("test@google.com"));
        generateMailMessage.setSubject("Greetings from Crunchify.com..");
        String emailBody = "Test email by Crunchify.com JavaMail API example. " + "<br><br> Regards, <br>Crunchify Admin";
        generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
        System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");

//Step3     
        System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
        Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        // Enter your correct gmail UserID and Password
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "***my google user name ****", "**** my google password *****");
        transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

The error that I get from this is:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at Mail.generateAndSendEmail(Mail.java:50)
    at Mail.main(Mail.java:21)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 5 more
```

I'm successfully able to telnet into smtp.gmail.com 587 and get the response back
     220 mx.google.com ESMTP k66sm21937006yhg.39 - gsmtp

The line of code that's having problem is: 
    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "***my google user name ****", "**** my google password *****");

I'm replacing ***my google user name **** and **** my google password **** with my google login credentials.  If anyone could help me figure this out I'd be just so happy as I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: The solution listed on the other thread that this is a duplicate does not work.  I received a new error when I tried it.  Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target